# Apache Curator Unimplemented Errors When Trying to Create zNodes

Tags: apache, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

I'm attempting to use Apache Curator with a dockerized zookeeper instance and no matter how I attempt to connect I always end up with a

> org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$UnimplementedException:
>   KeeperErrorCode = Unimplemented for...

error. I've tried making sense of the documentation but I'm not getting anywhere. I've logged into the zookeeper CLI and ensured the port number is correct thusly:

```
snerd@powerglove:~$ docker ps CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS   NAMES 31f1093495ba        compose_zookeeper   "/opt/zookeeper/bin/   3 weeks ago         Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:32770->2181/tcp,
0.0.0.0:32769->2888/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32768->3888/tcp   zookeeper
```

here is the code I'm trying to use:

```
public class App {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        CuratorFramework client = CuratorFrameworkFactory.newClient("0.0.0.0:32770", new RetryUntilElapsed(3000, 1000));
        client.start();

            try {
                client.create().forPath("/larry-smells/foop", "tuna?".getBytes());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.toString());
            }

    }
}
```

As far as I can tell from the [Curator getting started page](https://curator.apache.org/getting-started.html), this should work. What am I missing?

**edit1**
just figured out that I'm able to pull data out of the zookeeper ensemble thusly:

```
System.out.println(new String(curatorFramework.getData().forPath("/larry-smells")));
```

but the create command is still blowing up.

**edit2**

stacktrace of the error:

> org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$UnimplementedException:
>   KeeperErrorCode = Unimplemented for /larry-smells/foop    at
>   org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:103)
>     at
>   org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
>     at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.create(ZooKeeper.java:1297)   at
>   org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl$17.call(CreateBuilderImpl.java:1040)
>     at
>   org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl$17.call(CreateBuilderImpl.java:1023)
>     at
>   org.apache.curator.connection.StandardConnectionHandlingPolicy.callWithRetry(StandardConnectionHandlingPolicy.java:67)
>     at org.apache.curator.RetryLoop.callWithRetry(RetryLoop.java:99)    at
>   org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl.pathInForeground(CreateBuilderImpl.java:1020)
>     at
>   org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl.protectedPathInForeground(CreateBuilderImpl.java:501)
>     at
>   org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl.forPath(CreateBuilderImpl.java:491)
>     at
>   org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl$4.forPath(CreateBuilderImpl.java:367)
>     at
>   org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl$4.forPath(CreateBuilderImpl.java:309)
>     at com.mycompany.app.App.main(App.java:35)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

---

Edit: Apparently this error can occur if you're using the wrong combination of Curator in combination with Zookeeper. From [curator.apache.org](http://curator.apache.org/) :

> Curator 2.x.x - compatible with both ZooKeeper 3.4.x and ZooKeeper 3.5.x
>
> Curator 3.x.x - compatible only with ZooKeeper 3.5.x and includes support for new features such as dynamic reconfiguration, etc.

---

It's hard to pinpoint your problem with only that error-code and not a stack trace, but some improvements I would suggest to make your application more stable is:

```java
public class App {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        CuratorFramework client = CuratorFrameworkFactory.newClient("0.0.0.0:32770", new RetryUntilElapsed(3000, 1000));
        client.start();

        try {
            //make sure you're connected to zookeeper.
            client.blockUntilConnected();

            //Make sure the parents are created.
            client.create().creatingParentsIfNeeded().forPath("/larry-smells/foop", "tuna?".getBytes());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            }

    }
}
```

Comment: made your suggested change and got same result. I also added the stack trace to the text of the question.

Comment: doots -- turns out I'm a dink. the issue was plainly stated in a warning at the bottom of the curator homepage regarding using only v2 with zookeeper versions < 3.5.x. Basically I failed to RTFM. If you put that in the form of an answer I'll accept it so at least you get some cred for your trouble :-)

Answer (score 3):

I also faced a similar exception, I used the below dependencies which are compatible and helps me to resolve the exception.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
        <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.curator</groupId>
        <artifactId>curator-framework</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.curator</groupId>
        <artifactId>curator-x-discovery</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

I tried to use inTransaction () as explained here: http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.apache.curator.framework.CuratorFramework on exercise 6
and seems to work.

```
client.inTransaction ().create().forPath("/larry-smells/foop", "tuna?".getBytes()).and ().commit ();
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very useful, especially the inTransaction()

Answer (score 1):

The issue is caused because of incompatibility.

To fix this, you need to change the version like it's explained here:
https://curator.apache.org/zk-compatibility.html

If this doesn't work, just look for the newest curator version which depends on a 3.4.x zookeeper version (currently `'2.12.0'`).

Answer (score 0):

@Massimo Da Ros solution works, but in new version Curator 4.0.0 inTransaction is deprecated, it's recommented use `transaction` method like below:

```
CuratorOp op = client.transactionOp().create()
            .withMode(CreateMode.PERSISTENT)
            .withACL(Ids.OPEN_ACL_UNSAFE)
            .forPath("/test", "Data".getBytes());
result = client.transaction().forOperations(op).get(0).toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced similiar problem. I was using `spring-cloud-starter-zookeeper-discovery` which by itself of course has compatible zookeeper and curator versions.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zookeeper-discovery</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

I checked the dependency tree and `spring-cloud-starter-zookeeper-discovery` Version `3.1.1`. was using `zookeeper` Version `3.6.0`

The problem was, in my docker-compose.yml I was using zookeeper Version 3.4!

So make sure your `docker-compose.yml` zookeeper version fits your maven zookeeper version.

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  zookeeper:
    container_name: zookeeper
    image: zookeeper:3.6  <----------------- zookeeper version
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
```