# Zookeeper : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.zookeeper.admin.ZooKeeperAdmin after updating spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, maven, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator, spring-cloud-zookeeper

I am trying to update an springboot application which uses `org.apache.zookeeper.zookeeper`.
After updating the spring boot version. I am getting one of the two errors given below depending upon the version used.

**Error 1** - (For new version provided below)

```
Caused by: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$UnimplementedException: KeeperErrorCode = Unimplemented for /service/**/test/**/************
        at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:106)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:54)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.create(ZooKeeper.java:1836)
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl$16.call(CreateBuilderImpl.java:1131)
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl$16.call(CreateBuilderImpl.java:1113)
        at org.apache.curator.RetryLoop.callWithRetry(RetryLoop.java:93)
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl.pathInForeground(CreateBuilderImpl.java:1110)
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl.protectedPathInForeground(CreateBuilderImpl.java:593)
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl.forPath(CreateBuilderImpl.java:583)
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl.forPath(CreateBuilderImpl.java:48)
        at org.apache.curator.x.discovery.details.ServiceDiscoveryImpl.internalRegisterService(ServiceDiscoveryImpl.java:237) 
        at org.apache.curator.x.discovery.details.ServiceDiscoveryImpl.registerService(ServiceDiscoveryImpl.java:192)
        at org.springframework.cloud.zookeeper.serviceregistry.ZookeeperServiceRegistry.register(ZookeeperServiceRegistry.java:71)
        ... 63 more
```

or

**Error 2** - (For some other versions of zookeeper and curator provided in thread 1 provided below)

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.zookeeper.admin.ZooKeeperAdmin
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        ... 109 more
```

Old versions: (Working good)
Java - 8
SpringBoot - 2.3.3.RELEASE
Zookeeper - 3.4.12
Curator - 4.0.1

New version: (Spring managed versions)
Java - 8
SpringBoot - 2.7.4
Zookeeper - 3.6.0
Curator - 5.1.0

Many threads mentions that the issue is because of incompatible zookeeper and curator versions.

There are some threads already available regarding the issue

- [Zookeeper : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.zookeeper.admin.ZooKeeperAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66969356/zookeeper-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-zookeeper-admin-zookeep)
  I tried every solution provided in the this thread and also some other combinations but none seems to work. I tried to use the old version and updating the rest. This too didn't work.
- [Apache Curator Unimplemented Errors When Trying to Create zNodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35734590/apache-curator-unimplemented-errors-when-trying-to-create-znodes)
  I am not accessing the curator directly as provided in this thread and I believe the zookeeper internally uses curator.

Is there any other dependency I need to upgrade? or Do I need to upgrade the java?
Please mention if you need some more info.

Comment: Have you check the upgrades information in Spring Boot Release notes for the different versions. Also true for Zookeeper...

Comment: @khmarbaise - Yes, I have checked the spring-boot release notes and there is no mention of major changes on zookeeper or actuator. Just some minor bug fixes. I have gone through the zookeeper release notes too but it's a rabbit hole. There is a ton of changes between the mentioned versions.

Comment: can you put a reproducer to github ?

Comment: This looks like a problem in your project dependencies. Please share the relevant parts of your pom.xml or build.gradle

Comment: These should be compatible, there must be some library in a offending version. You need to inspect output of `mvn dependency:tree` and stack traces ending with to ClassNotFound to identify that library. Posting these details may help to get more precise answer.